# Por que "var" força inferência de tipo?

Tags: dart, inferência

Realizando alguns testes com a linguagem eu notei que quando utilizamos a palavra chave var o Dart vai "forçar" a inferência de tipo, mas quando utilizamos um tipo para declarar variáveis isso não acontece.

O teste que fiz:

```dart
main(){
  Map a = {
    '6': 6,
  };
  var b = {
    '6': 6,
  };
  a[7] = '7'; // Executa sem erros
  b[7] = '7'; //Erro
}
```

Por que uma declaração com um tipo não força inferência enquanto que com var força?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos ver que tipo ele inferiu e qual o tipo pego quando foi explícito:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:mirrors'; 
 
void main() {
    Map a = {
        '6' : 6,
    };
    var b = {
        '6' : 6,
    };
    print(reflect(a).type.reflectedType.toString());
    print(reflect(b).type.reflectedType.toString());
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Isw4nS). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/InferenceMapdt). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Dart/InferenceMap.dt).

No primeiro você especificou qual era o tipo, mas não ele completo, faltou os tipos de chave e valor. Por alguma razão a linguagem decidiu (se não for um *bug* do compilador, mas acho que foi planejado assim mesmo) que você deveria usar o tipo completo, portanto dizer quais os tipos da chave e o valor do mapa, ou então ele consideraria que você não quer um tipo específico e aí ele assumiria que você quer algo dinâmico.

Quando estabelece que usará algo dinâmico muita coisa fica livre, o compilador não detecta erros de tipo ali e permite executar, mesmo que não produza o que você espera. No caso ele permitiu trocar o tipo do dado da chave e do valor porque você aceitou que o compilador inferisse que quer, o que entendemos pela sua pergunta ser equivocado, `dynamic`. É mais ou menos como uma variável que o valor dela seja 0 se você não colocar valor algum. Se você quer que ela valha 1 então tem que ser explícito.

Quando mandou inferir o compilador inferiu os três tipos possíveis ali, e aí não conseguiu executar algo irregular porque a chave e o valor possuem tipo específico, portanto a chave foi inferida como `string` e você está usando um número, e o valor foi inferido como `int` e você está tentando colocar um caractere.

Dart tem se mostrado uma linguagem com decisões questionáveis e por ser uma linguagem moderna que pode aprender com os erros das outras faz pensar sobre a qualidade ela (não que afete o futuro, muitas linguagens muito mal pensadas tiveram sucesso, inclusive ela terá sucesso por causa de um framework e não porque ela é boa, isso nunca dá muito certo). Inclusive é ruim por ser inconsistente, e gera dúvidas como essa.

Pior ainda é que ela exige que você seja explícito que quer a inferência quando obriga o uso do `var`, e no caso do `Map` sem você dizer nada ela inferiu os tipos internos. Então tem dois erros, se você quisesse que ele inferisse o que inferiu deveria obrigar fazer um `Map<var, var>`, e deveria usar o mesmo critério e encontrar o tipo específico, o `dynamic` nunca deveria ser opção principal do compilador. Ou então deveria ser sempre a opção principal, mas aí a linguagem tenderia a ser mais dinâmica, e todas as regras deveriam refletir isso, na falta de algo explícito deveria ser `dynamic`, nunca deveria obrigar o uso do `var`.

Parece que Dart não sabe se quer ser uma linguagem dinâmica ou estática. Se quisesse ser estática ela inferiria a parte que não está explícita, ou então daria erro dizendo que não tem o tipo completo e te obrigando a colocar um `dynamic` se é o que deseja. Prefiro o primeiro, e se quer o dinamismo que seja explícito.

Para mim foi um erro de *design* da linguagem, mas eles devem ter uma justificativa pra fazer isso, mesmo que seja uma pra justificar depois que o erro foi cometido. Tem linguagem que adora fazer isso.

[image: Bug, Feature and By Design, baratas, uma pelada, outra vestindo terninho e ainda terninho remendado]

A lição é nunca usar uma declaração com tipo incompleto, ou deixa inferir tudo ou coloca todo o tipo. Isto seria o correto:

```
Map<string, int> a = {
    '6': 6,
};
```

ou, claro, deixar inferir tudo.

Sabendo da regra pode-se usar corretamente, só não pode esquecer dela, que não é intuitiva.

Comment: Acho que o motivo do "Map A" ter os tipos dinâmicos é por isso: "The static type of a map literal of the form const {k1 : e1,...,kn : en} or the form {k1 : e1,...,kn : en} is Map<dynamic, dynamic>." e se levar a seguinte frase ao pé da letra "... you can use var and let Dart infer the type: ..." tudo se explica.